# Why does WebStorm not recognise or understand Angular services?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webstorm

I have an Angular 1 service defined as follows :

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

   angular.module('app').service('MyService',MyService);

   function MyService(){ 
       this.myFunction  = myFunction;
       function myFunction(){}
   }

})();
```

But in WebStorm I am getting little squigglies because I haven't used an anonymous function. Does anyone know how I can let WebStorm know about this?

[image]

**NOTE** : I have already added Angular in the WebStorm menu. And I have already 'right clicked' on the document and clicked 'use JavaScript library'.

Comment: Using `MyService.prototype.myFunction = function () {}` should be the preferred way to specify "class" methods, and that might solve your problem too.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using inline JSdoc here to let WebStorm know what argument type is, like:

```
it('my test', inject(function (/** MyService*/MyService) {

    expect(MyService.myFunction()).toBeFalsy()

  }))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return 'myFunction' :
return {
myFunction:myFunction 
}